# ListView deletion only on click

Tags: wpf, listview, selectionchanged

I have a ListView with a specific ItemTemplate, which visually displays the contents of a list of objects. I wanted to allow the user to select such an object by clicking on it, and as a consequence of selecting it, it will be loaded as the application's current object and deleted from the list.

The problem is that the listview doesn't support Click events, so I tried using the SelectionChanged event. Well, this isn't ok as well, because if I click on an item (but without releasing the mouse) and then I move the mouse over another item (while keeping the mouse pressed), it deletes that item as well.

Any suggestions on how I can delete the selected item from the list without triggering additional operations? here's a simplified version of my code (which has the same behaviour):

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="lstNumbers"  SelectionMode="Single"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="lstNumbers_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>                
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="170" Background="Transparent">                        
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding val, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="3"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Name="btnAddItem" Grid.Row="1" Click="btnAddItem_Click">Add Item</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class valueClass
        {
            public int val { get; set; }
        }
        private List<valueClass> list;
        private int counter;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateList();
            DisplayList();
        }

        private void CreateList()
        {
            list = new List<valueClass>();
            counter = 8;
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new valueClass() { val = i + 1 });
            }
        }

        private void lstNumbers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstNumbers.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                list.Remove(lstNumbers.SelectedValue as valueClass);
                DisplayList();
            }
        }

        private void DisplayList()
        {
            this.lstNumbers.ItemsSource = null;
            this.lstNumbers.ItemsSource = list;
        }

        private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            list.Add(new valueClass() { val = counter++ + 1 });
            DisplayList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you can catch clicks if you set a click handler in the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx)?

Comment: For future reference, an ObserveableCollection is a better source to bind to as anytime you remove/add an item, it'll be reflected in the listview automagically. That way you won't have to unbind and rebind your source to see changes reflected like you did in DisplayList(). Something to consider for next time, or this time, if you wanted to make things easier on yourself.

Comment: @Yatrix: I have the same problem even if I used an ObservableCollection. The problem is not the data source, but the list view's behaviour.

Comment: @melculetz oh, I know. I meant for future reference as the source, not a solution to the problem. That's why I didn't include it in my answer. Was just a suggestion for future use with listviews and itemsources. The nice thing about them is changes to the source changes the listview and vice versa if you bind it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this in an answer so it stands out from the comment wall there.

Since you are removing on selectionchanged, anytime that changes, you're deleting. Try using your remove logic in PreviewMouseUp and then grabbing the item there. That way, clicking down on something won't remove the item until you're click is finished.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and avoid code behind, and adopt the [MVVM design pattern](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html). In this case, you would bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView` (although there is no reason this couldn't be a `ListBox` instead), and then just remove the `SelectedItem` in your view model from the collection in response a change in its value.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. MVVM isn't a pattern for all WPF applications. There's nothing wrong with code-behind while using WPF, especially in a smaller application that probably won't benefit from all that extra "stuff". You should never complicate something simple. He asked for a solution to his problem and what you suggested is rewriting his application - a bit extreme, don't you think?

Comment: True, but the biggest reasons for using MVVM are code reuse and testability, and those are features that any application can benefit from.

Comment: I 100% agree with it's merits and I actually am enjoying getting into MVVM. But where he's at, he may not be able to rewrite everything to meet the pattern and a small program won't benefit from the overhead of MVVM to warrant it's use.

Comment: Yes, that may be the case in this example, but I find with the use of MVVM frameworks, development is just as quick, if not quicker with MVVM.

Comment: well, I think when a question is asked, for the sake of the OP, helping him out with what he has is the best way to go. I'm not in disagreement about the use of the pattern by any stretch. I just think answers should be question specific, that's all.

Comment: I think in this case, my suggestion not only will solve the problem, but will make the app more maintainable, testable, and better quality in general. Plus start as you mean to go on I say.

Comment: But he wasn't asking how he could make his app more maintainable, testable and of better quality. He asked for a solution to his deletion issue and you failed to provide that for him. I agree with what you're saying about programming in general, I'm only disagreeing with what you provided for the OP as a "solution".

Comment: Then he doesn't have to accept this answer. Feel free to write your own.

Comment: @devdigital: thank you for the OP suggestion, but it's not a solution to my problem. And I assure you, there is a reason why I used ListView instead of ListBox (as I said, the sample code is a simplified version of the actual case) - probably one of the reasons why the WPF team created ListView in the first place, instead of offering just the ListBox option

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
private void lstNumbers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstNumbers.SelectedIndex != -1)
            { 
                lstNumbers.SelectionChanged-=lstNumbers_SelectionChanged;
                list.Remove(lstNumbers.SelectedValue as valueClass);
                DisplayList();
                lstNumbers.SelectionChanged+=lstNumbers_SelectionChanged;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some more explanation to this.